# Python csv reader returns formula instead of value

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a txt file which has some 'excel formulas', I have converted this to a csv file using Python csv reader/writer. Now I want to read the values of the csv file and do some calculation, but when i try to access the particular column of .csv file, it still returns me in the 'excel formula' instead of the actual value?? although When i open the csv file .. formulas are converted in to value??
Any ideas?

Here is the code

Code to convert txt to csv

```
def parseFile(filepath):

    file = open(filepath,'r')
    content = file.read()
    file.close()

    lines = content.split('\n')

    csv_filepath = filepath[:(len(filepath)-4)]+'_Results.csv'
    csv_out = csv.writer(open(csv_filepath, 'a'), delimiter=',' , lineterminator='\n')             
    for line in lines:

                data = line.split('\t')
                csv_out.writerow(data)   

   return csv_filepath
```

Code to do some calculation in csv file

```
def csv_cal (csv_filepath):


    r = csv.reader(open(csv_filepath)) 

    lines = [l for l in r]
    counter =[0]*(len(lines[4])+6)

    if lines[4][4] == 'Last Test Pass?' :
        print ' i am here'

        for i in range(0,3):
            print lines[6] [4]  ### RETURNS FORMULA ??


    return 0
```

I am new to python, any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks,

Comment: Can your data begin with `=`? If so you might want to insert a `'` before the value to get Excel to stop treating it as a formula.

Comment: Also, do you have to use Excel? Could you open the file in a text editor instead?

Comment: CSV data files are no spreadsheets; they only contain data. Why do you expect formulas to be executed?

Answer (score 1):

You can **paste special** in Excel with **Values only** option selected. You could select all and paste into a another sheet and save. This would save you from having to implement some kind of parser in python. Or, you could evaluate some simple arithmetic with `eval`.

edit:

I've heard of [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) which can be downloaded from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd). It loads .xls files.

It sounded like you just wanted the final data which past special can do.

Comment: Using `eval` is a very bad idea. Anything from a spreadsheet that `ast.literal_eval` can't handle, `eval` probably won't help; it'll just open the door for harder-to-understand errors, bizarre unexplained misbehavior, and the usual security holes.